# Custom watch action

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I want to use the watch action to share a "GIF" object but i am not allowed. I already know that the watch command is built in and it can only be used with videos, episodes etc.

After some research i found that gifboom.com its allow to use the watch command as custom command. Please see http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/7240/capturefhv.png

Also the link contains this:  fb_action_types=gifboom:watch so it looks they were allowed to use watch as a custom action.

How can i request a custom watch command for my application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way to do this now.

> For developers building video apps, we have created a common Watch
>   action. This action can only refer to a built-in video-type object
>   such as Movie, TV Show, TV Episode or Video. As a convenience, these
>   built-in video-type objects are automatically added when you register
>   the built-in Watch action for your app.
>
> NOTE: Submissions for a custom Watch action will no longer be
>   accepted. If your object isn't of type Movie, TV Show, or TV Episode,
>   you should use the general-purpose built-in Video object type.

FYI: [Builtin Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/)

Comment: Yes i know, i've read that. But how gifboom manage to do that? You can see in the link structure that they action is watch.

Comment: I guess it was approved earlier before they apply this restriction.

Comment: Thank you @Venu. So at one point you were able to add custom object to the watch command right? So i guess i should replace the watch action with a custom view one.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your action something else, f.e. „look” instead of watch, and see if you can get it through the approval process …